# Firebase dynamic link not received after install from play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In my scenario, I am generating a dynamic link in my app with some analytics parameter and using below line of code

```
.setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("XX.XXX.debug").build())
```

Which is working fine, the short link is being generated, when I tap on the link from some other window it opens my app and the dynamic link is captured in my splash screen successfully. This was debug version of my app.

Later, I thought of testing it on the release version as well. So, I generated a release apk and also modified the above lines of code to this

```
.setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("XX.XXX").build())
```

removing the debug part from it. I posted my app on ALPHA channel of playstore.

I re-installed the release version from playstore, generated the link and copied it. Now to test the deeplink, I uninstalled the release version of my app.

So Far So Good!!

Now I tapped on the copied link generated from the release version previously, it opens the play store, redirects to my app , the alpha version gets installed.

I tapped open button from playstore and my app launches the splash screen where the deep link is supposed to be detected.

**PROBLEM 1 -> the deep link is not being detected**

**PROBLEM 2 -> tapping again on that deeplink should open my app but it opens the play store.**

Please Help!

**EDIT**
My intent filter looks like this

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xxxx.app.goo.gl"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="xxxx.app.goo.gl"
                android:pathPattern=".*"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: For problem 1: We have had some reports of alpha channel installs from the Play store not sending the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast - Dynamic Links depends on that to get the deep link.

Comment: For problem 2: Can you check you have an intent filter set up in your manifest for the other domain (feel free to edit with the question to include your manifest and domains if easier)

Comment: @IanBarber - for problem 1, can I expect that this works in the PRODUCTION channel, or when can I expect a fix.

Comment: @IanBarber - for problem 2- i have made an edit on your request, posted my intent filter.

Comment: Problem 1: yes, should work in production.

Comment: @IanBarber I just pushed the code to production. It isn't working.

Comment: Best bet at this point is to file a ticket with support - include the handling code, manifest app details and an example link if you can.

Comment: @IanBarber just reported the bug to firebase department.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add intent filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#add-an-intent-filter-for-deep-links) for the domain your links are actually on. You can think of a dynamic link as a wrapper for your regular link.

So rather than adding a filter for myapp.app.goo.gl, you'd add a filter for myapp.com.

Answer (score -1):

HI  in first there is two Builder Constructor 
1. default Constructor that means open your App 
2. Constructor  take open parameter String that mean if you want URl
so the solve issue is

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.jo/");
    Uri uri1 = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("order", "725").build();
    DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(uri1)
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("rw4r7.app.goo.gl")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.example.android")
                            .setMinimumVersion(1)
                            .build())
            // Open links with this app on Android
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            .setGoogleAnalyticsParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.GoogleAnalyticsParameters.Builder()
                            .setSource("orkut")
                            .setMedium("social")
                            .setCampaign("example-promo")
                            .build())
            .setItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.ItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters.Builder()
                            .setProviderToken("123456")
                            .setCampaignToken("example-promo")
                            .build())
            .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                            .setTitle("Example of a Dynamic Link")
                            .setDescription("This link works whether the app is installed or not!")
                            .build())
            // Open links with com.example.ios on iOS
            .buildDynamicLink();

    Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
    Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(uri1)
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("rw4r7.app.goo.gl")
            .setLongLink(dynamicLinkUri)

            // Set parameters
            // ...
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shortLink.toString());
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        intent.putExtra("testsawalha", "testSawalha");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // Error
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
```